# How to remove assignment of products in a category in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, assign

I am iterating through a list of products in Magento. I do assign new category Ids with `setCategoryIds()` but old assignments are not going to be removed.
Like product A is in Category X. Now I want A in Category Y and Z and out of X. I do a setCategoryIds(Y,Z) and now the product is in X,Y and Z.

How to remove it programmatically without using the SOAP API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, `setCategoryIds` should reset all previous categories, if they are not among the ones that are set. I've created a test shell script **test.php** to test it:

```
<?php
require_once 'abstract.php';

/**
 * Magento Test Assignment Script
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Shell
 */
class Mage_Shell_Test extends Mage_Shell_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Run script
     *
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $productId = $this->getArg('product');
        $catIdsString = $this->getArg('categories');
        $catIds = explode(',', $catIdsString);
        /** @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
        $product->setCategoryIds($catIds);
        $product->save();
        print_r($product->getCategoryIds());
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Usage Help Message
     *
     */
    public function usageHelp()
    {
        return <<<USAGE
Usage:  php -f test.php -- [options]
        php -f test.php -- --product 1 --categories 3,4

  --product <product>       Product Id
  --categories <categories> Categories to assign, comma separated
  help                      This help

USAGE;
    }
}

$shell = new Mage_Shell_Test();
$shell->run();
```

You can insert it into your `shell` folder and try to run association.

Comment: Ok, tried it out with a product which was in category 14,15 and 18. Set it to 15 and 20 and the result was 14,15,18 and 20... I really don't get it...

Comment: there's something messed up with your code than... try to turn off all of your custom modules and see if the issue persists. Also it would be useful to look inside the error logs, maybe something crushes during the product save process

Comment: `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category_api')->assignProduct($category->getId(),$product->getId())` is what I was using before, which just adds to the category. `$product->setCategoryIds($catIds)` helped with cleaning up the categories, to only set what I say to set, and purge any other category.

Comment: I also want to add that through the `getSingleton` you can remove a product from a category by this `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category_api')->removeProduct($category->getId(),$product->getId());`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

$categoryId = 5; // Put here your category id
$storeId = 1; // You can add store level

$assignedProducts = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'category.assignedProducts', array($categoryId, $storeId));
var_dump($assignedProducts); // Will output assigned products.

// Assign product
$proxy->call($sessionId, 'category.assignProduct', array($categoryId, 'someProductSku', 5));

// Update product assignment postion
$proxy->call($sessionId, 'category.updateProduct', array($categoryId, 'someProductSku', 25));

// Remove product assignment
$proxy->call($sessionId, 'category.removeProduct', array($categoryId, 'someProductSku'));
```

Follow this link:[See Here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogCategory/catalogCategory.html)

Comment: I should have mentioned that. The customer does not allow to use the SOAP API. There must be a way without that...